# Form submit keeps looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

PHere is what is supposed to happen:

on button click, the submit of the form is disabled. then a text swap runs. Upon the completion of the text swap, the var of cancel switches to false and then submits the form.

The problem is that once the form.submit() fires, it loops and the text fades in and out, continually. This also causes the form not to submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cancel = true;

    $("#btn-submit").click(

    function () {
        if (cancel == true) {
            $('form').on('submit', function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                form = $(".submit-form");
                fp = $('#free-planner');
                fp.fadeOut(350, function () {
                    fp.text('Check your email!');
                });
                fp.fadeIn(350, function () {
                    cancel = false;
                    if (cancel == false) {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How can your form be ever submitted if you cancel its default action - which is `submit`? )

Comment: @raina77ow that appears to be the goal with `form.submit()`.  That triggers the event to submit the form after applying the user's desired submission logic first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the loop by setting the cancel variable to false and then stating that so long as it is false, submit the form.

Try the following:

```
var cancel = true;

$("#btn-submit").click(function () {
    if (cancel == true) {
        form = $(".submit-form");
        fp = $('#free-planner');
        fp.fadeOut(350, function () {
            fp.text('Check your email!');
        });
        fp.fadeIn(350, function () {                                       
            if (cancel == true) { 
               cancel = false;           
               form.submit();                     
            }                 
        });
    }
});
```

This modifies your logic slightly to check if the cancel variable has not been modified from it's original state, true, then modify the state to false and then submit the form.  This results in the form only being submitted once.

In addition, if `btn-submit` is the submit button then change the input type to `button` instead of `submit`,  Making this change means that you do not need to add the listener to the onSubmit event as the button itself is meant to serve as the submit event.  This also alleviates the need to call `preventDefault()` on the event as the event does not occur until it is triggered with `form.submit()`.

Comment: I believe this is the right track Rob, btn-submit is the submit button. I am unsure of how to modify the onSubmit event in the way you propose. The onSubmit is currently not set.

Comment: Using your method fixes the looping issue, however the form still does not submit. Removing preventDefault() causes the form to automatically submit before the function has run.

Comment: @JakePump - Removing the preventDefault() is only one portion of it. The additional part is to remove the event listener for onSubmit() [$('form').on('submit', function (ev) {] and to modify the input type from `submit` to `button` if possible. I've updated the snippet to include the full portion of code you provided.

Comment: Eureka! Thats fixed it. Thanks so much for your help @RobB . I just couldn't get my head around it. Switching the type from submit to button proved to be a key piece I had not thought of.

Comment: @JakePump - I personally always try to go that route when I want a "faux" submit button, instead of having to worry about the default action.